# Usnig session as instance variable

Tags: java, session, servlets

Many methods of my Servlet use HTTPSession. It is thread-safety to declare HTTPSession variable as instance variable?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By defaut Servlets are not thread safe**. And moreover, a servlets instance will invoked for many clients. **It is absolutely wrong to have session as instance variable.**

*Reference:*

[Is a Servlet thread-safe](http://www.coderanch.com/t/473015/Servlets/java/Servlet-thread-safe)

[Write thread safe servlets](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0712-threadsafe.html)

Comment: even if I get session variable by getThreadLocalRequest.getSession() ?

Comment: @Hello: What is `getThreadLocalRequest()`? Do you use any framework?

Comment: getThreadLocalRequest() means getting the thread local object.  which is thread safe becuase before on every request intialization the thread local would have been set. I am not sure which framework it is, i just have reffered you some useful links.

Comment: ok thanks.. i.e. if I get session using thredLocal I can set this session as instance variable?

Comment: No, just use request.getSession(). You can use thread local when you want to access session in classes other than servlets which do not have request or session variable readily available.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe. a servlet is created when the application starts. The Servlet has only one instance (which means multiple requests/clients use the same servlet), which is why you should avoid having any instance variables.

Comment: But session is unique object  for each user. So even if I get session by  getThreadLocalRequest.getSession()  it is not thread-safe?